# Can't access anymore from SSH to CentOS5.7

Tags: networking, ssh, centos, connection, centos-5

I have made an update to CentOS5.7 and since then I can't access by SSH to the machine. I have disable the Firewall and I have the "sshd" service active.

I got the following when I do this from the local machine(localhost):

```
$ ssh andre@192.168.229.136
ssh: connect to host 192.168.229.136 port 22: Connection refused

$ ssh andre@192.168.229.136:22
ssh: 192.168.229.136:22 Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Can someone give me a clue on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check, if the machine really runs sshd on port 22:

```
# netstat -4nl | grep ":22"
```

and if the machine really has the ip `192.168.229.136`:

```
# ifconfig
```

and if the machine can be pinged from where you want to access it:

```
# ping 192.168.229.136
```

your 2nd command is faulty because it means `connect to the machine with the name '192.168.229.136:22' (and since your dns-resolver is not able to map that name to a valid ip you got 'temporary failure in name resolution'). the flag to set the port is '-p'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The ssh service was down... Thanks again